# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

So I understand the idea behind async/await is just a prettier way to use promises but apparently I'm not understanding it correctly.

```
async function a(): Promise <number> {
  return 5;
}
```

This is fine, returns a promise that is resolved with result 5.

```
async function a(): Promise <number> {
  return await new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(5);
  });
}
```

> error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'.
>   Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.

From what I understand, await will wait for the promise to resolve and return the result, which in this case is 5 and should work as the above example?

Comment: `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'` seems like a far more appropriate title.

Comment: Why are you using promise with async/await?

Comment: @HarshPatel how else would you write this if you have a function that works with callbacks inside `a()`?

Comment: I opened a bug on the type warning: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23114 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the `new Promise()` is equivalent to `new Promise<{}>`.

You inner Promise returns not a number, but an object. You need to ensure to compiler that it is a Promise with the type number.

Replace `await new Promise` with `await new Promise<number>`

```
async function a(): Promise<number> {
  return await new Promise<number>(resolve => {
    resolve(5);
  });
}
```

And check your code also, I think you can work with your code without the middle Promise

```
async function a(): Promise<number> {
      return await 5;
}
```

Comment: It was a simplified example, obviously I need the middle promise :D